# In R, how do I find the x value that will equate to a certain y value on a cdplot? And vice-versa?

Tags: r, probability, distribution

I have a cdplot where I'm trying to find my x value where the distribution (or the y value) = .5 and couldn't find a method to do it that works. Additionally I want to find the y value when my x value is 0 and would like help finding that equation to if it's different.

I cant really provide my code as it relies on a saved workspace with a large dataframe. I'll give this as an example:

`fail <- factor(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1,1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),levels = 1:2, labels = c("no", "yes"))
temperature <- c(53, 57, 58, 63, 66, 67, 67, 67, 68, 69, 70, 70,70, 70, 72, 73, 75, 75, 76, 76, 78, 79, 81)
cdplot(fail ~ temperature)`

So I don't need a quick and dirty way to solve this specific example, I need a code I can apply to my own workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you capture the return of `cdplot`, you get a function that you can use to find these values.

```
CDP = cdplot(fail ~ temperature
uniroot(function(x) { CDP$no(x) - 0.5}, c(55,80))
> uniroot(function(x) { CDP$no(x) - 0.5}, c(55,80))
$root
[1] 62.34963
$f.root
[1] 3.330669e-16
```